# GA4 purchase event function in Debug View, but not seeing the event in list

Tags: google-analytics, event-handling, google-tag-manager

I setup (via Tag manager) a tag and a trigger for the Purchase page.  When I do a test purchase, I see the "purchase event" in the debug view of GA4

[image]

I've waited 24 hours, and I still don't see my "purchase event" in the list of event

[image]

Any idea why?  Is it because my "debug_mode = 1" ?  I made a test purchase from shopify with the test mode enable.

[image]

Inside the "preview mode" of Google Tag Manager, everything is fine. I see my event with the proper parameter values for the purchase.

Any idea why?

Comment: Sometimes you might need to wait longer. Document claims 24 to 48 hours. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9333790?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events with `debug_mode = 1` will not show up in GA4.

Using GTM in "preview mode" automatically enables "debug mode".

See [Debug Mode](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7201382?hl=en)

Comment: ok, thank you. That must be it then.